# After uploading new build to iTunes I got push notification entitlement issue

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Name of app". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to
>   correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

The main information here

> If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service

but I have not added any push notification API methods.

How can I check which library uses Push Notification method or frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the Apple's verifying software. You could ignore it.

From https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15011 :

> I investigated this issue in MachO View to confirm it's a
>   false-positive.
>
> I could see that in AppDelegate.o - while there are no references to application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: in the symbol table..

```
$ nm ./AppDelegate.o | grep    application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken  
$
```

> I did find the grep output matching, as confirmed in other commenters' reports.

```
$ grep application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken ./AppDelegate.o  
Binary file ./AppDelegate.o matches
```

> I loaded the binary into MachO View (see screenshot below) and found application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:, application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithError: and ALL OF THE OTHER UIApplicationDelegate methods - in the __TEXT segment, __objc_methname section - the list of c string literals that store objc selector names
>
> MachO View Screenshot of __TEXT,__objc_methname section with list of UIApplicationDelegate methods:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5OWn.jpg
>
> I confirmed this finding with otool here:

```
$ otool -v -s __TEXT __objc_methname ./AppDelegate.o  | grep didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken  
000000000000bfbb  application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
```

> iTunes's review process is strings-based, not nm-based, so their simple grep for didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken will always register a false positive.